# Using variable names in Subsetting data in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame which i need to subset. 
Example dataFrame -

```
x           y               z           p         q
US          23              boy         34        45.6
EU          45              girl        27        24.67
US          23              boy         36        75.6
EU          45              girl        26        74.67
```

I understand that it can be done by -

```
subset(dataFrame, x == 'US')
```

Now, I have a usecase where i have a list of combinations to be applied over the dataFrame. 
dataFrame contains 5 columns - x,y,z,p,q
combinations as a dataFrame - 
1. x = US, y = 23, z = boy
2. x = EU, y = 34, z = girl

Now, these combinations can be any number, similarly we can have a bigger dataset. 
So, what i tried to do -
Example data set -

```
x           y               z
US          23              boy
EU          45              girl
```

combo is my dataFrame for combinations.

```
comboNames = names(combo)
subset(dataFrames, comboName[1] == lapply(combo[,1], as.character)[[1]])
```

This gives me 0 results.
However, If i do this -

```
subset(dataFrames, x == lapply(combo[,1], as.character)[[1]])
```

It works. 
Is it possible to represent this key x as a variable to extract out data. 
Hopefully, i am able to explain my question well enough. Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: Please include example input and output data using `dput()`

Comment: It is not very clear what your question is asking. Perhaps you can provide some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Added examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

comboName includes only the name(without reference to the dataframe). so the "x" that you get from comboName[1] is not referenced like the x in your second approach.
This should work:

```
 subset(dataframes, get(comboNames[1]) == lapply(combo[,1], as.character)[[1]])
```

I hope it is what you are looking for...

Cheers